# Popover not working for the select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, popover

Popover is not working for me. I have tried onChange and mouseover. With "mouseover" onChange() function is never hit. With "change" the onchange function is called but popover still doesn't work. 
I want onChange function to be called from another function. Here I am just giving the reference function() but In reality its internal function.

```
<select size="1" name = "selectList" id="selectList">
    <option value="1" data-info="data1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-info="data2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3" data-info="data3">Item 3</option>
    <option value="4" data-info="data4">Item 4</option>
</select>

$(function() {
//$("select[name=selectList]").on("change",onChange);
$("select[name=selectList]").on("mouseover",onChange); 
});
function onChange() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $e = $(this.target);
    $('#selectList').popover('destroy');
    $("#selectList").popover({
        trigger: 'manual',
        placement: 'right',
        content: $this.attr("data-info")
    }).popover('show');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xrkxdedg/1/

Comment: And where did you get `popover()` from ?

Comment: I am using popover for the first time, and believe that $("#selectList").popover({
        trigger: 'manual',
        placement: 'right',
        content: $this.attr("data-info")
    }) will create the popover object. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: He means what JQuery library are you using. I have checked Bootstrap and I think this is not what you are using. Please edit your question and provide the link where did you get the popover function

Comment: There is no `popover` in jQuery, so unless you're using a plugin, `popover` doesn't exist. There are hundreds of `popover` plugins available.

Comment: @jeremejazz Their JS looks like Bootstrap to me: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Answer (score 0):

Update your selector so that it targets the `option` tags which has the `data-info` attribute. Try changing `$this.attr("data-info")` to `$this.children('option:selected').attr("data-info")`.

```
function onChange() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $e = $(this.target);
    $('#selectList').popover('destroy');
    $("#selectList").popover({
        trigger: 'manual',
        placement: 'right',
        content: $this.children('option:selected').attr("data-info") //this
    }).popover('show');
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrkxdedg/3/)**